# Icon in material UI button

Tags: reactjs, icons, material-design, material-ui

I am new to react therefore I stuck with one thing and that is , I have delete icons injected in buttons and have multiple buttons on the front-end side, I want when any of the visible button clicked only that specific button can be deleted or disappear and remaining untouched buttons can still be visible on the front end page.

Any leads?

here is the sample code : https://codesandbox.io/s/reactjs-simple-conditional-rendering-example-gocg0

Thanks

Comment: Your condition to render ALL buttons is to check if `open`
You need to change the condiiton of displaying the buttons. Maybe an array of visible buttons  and then map over the array and return the component button. 
It is just an idea, it depends on your whole implementation of the app

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not store the open state of multiple buttons with a single `bool`.

You could use a list to store the displayed buttons:

```
const [openButtons, setOpenButtons] = React.useState([
  "Computer Science",
  "Business Adminstration",
  "Business Adminstration",
  "Media Studies",
  "Human Resources",
  "Udemy"
]);
```

Change the `handleClose` function to filter out the deleted item from the list:

```
function handleClose(buttonName) {
  setOpenButtons(
    openButtons.filter(openButtonName => openButtonName !== buttonName)
  );
}
```

And display the buttons if they are present in the stored list:

```
{openButtons.includes("Computer Science") && (
  <Button
    variant="contained"
    color="primary"
    className={classes.button}
    onClick={() => handleClose("Computer Science")}
  >
    Computer Science
    <DeleteIcon className={classes.rightIcon} />
  </Button>
)}
```

Here's the [codesandbox example](https://codesandbox.io/s/reactjs-simple-conditional-rendering-example-fur85).